# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: loops, exception, indexing

I am trying to display a list of song names, the user can add to this list but when I reach 6 songs, the consle displays the six songs along with this error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 6 out of bounds for length 6
Here is the code i am using

```
private static void getTrackList() {
        System.out.println("List all tracks.");
        System.out.println(count);
        if (myJukebox == null) {
            System.out.println(PROMPT + "Sorry, there are no tracks.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("We have the following tracks:");

            for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
                System.out.println(SPACES + (index + 1) + ". " + myJukebox.allTracks.get(index).getTitle());
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        return;

    }
```

Comment: Problem is not in this code, add code where you fill allTracks and 'count' variable. Why do you use separate count, instead of allTracks.count()?

Comment: Here is the code for the count 
public static int count = 0; 

and here is where the count is used in the addTrafck
// add object to the array
    myJukebox.addTrack(tk);
    // increment count
    count++;
Honestly im not to familiar with java so im not sure where ive done it this way